# Video Application Crash

Tags: java, android, galaxy

I have an application that is running the video automatically when you open the application , it was in the previous works fine, but when I put an audio file in the next activity.
It has become the application crashes when I turn it on.
Note: The operating system is Android 5.1.1
Put me the solution please.
My video code.

```js
                                                                                  
 public void splashPlayer() {                                                     
  VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);                 
  Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"            
          + R.raw.firstopenvideo);                                                
  videoView.setVideoURI(video);                                                   
  videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {      
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {                                  
      }                                                                           
  });                                                                             
  videoView.start();                                                              
 }
```

Comment: post your stack trace